# Clojure Ring: How to print a variable next to a string

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to set the Environment Variable known as `POWERED_BY` to the variable `message`.
Then I'd like to test if `message` is empty or NULL. Then print "Powered by" `message`.

Currently, the code below does not work.

```
(ns helloworld.web 
    (:use compojure.core [ring.adapter.jetty :only [run-jetty]] )
    (:require [compojure.route :as route]
              [compojure.handler :as handler]))


(defroutes main-routes
  ; what's going on
    (def message (System/getenv "POWERED_BY"))
    (GET "/" [] (apply str "Powered by " message))
    (route/resources "/")
    (route/not-found "Page not found")   )


(def app
    (handler/api main-routes))

(defn -main [port]
    (run-jetty app {:port (Integer. port)}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Define `message` outside routes definition:

```
 (def message (System/getenv "POWERED_BY"))

 (defroutes main-routes
  ; what's going on
 (GET "/" [] (str "Powered by " message)
 (route/resources "/")
 (route/not-found "Page not found"))
```

In case you want to retrieve the system environment variable value each time the request is received you can use the `let` form:

```
 (defroutes main-routes
  ; what's going on
 (GET "/" [] (let [message (System/getenv "POWERED_BY")]
                (str "Powered by " message))
 (route/resources "/")
 (route/not-found "Page not found"))
```

For *concat* just use `(str arg1 arg2 ...)`, `apply` works on lists, so if you want to use it you should do something like `(apply str ["Powered by" message])` instead.